# Checking if variable exists in javascript doesn;t work

Tags: javascript, variables

Tried:

```
var xxx = (typeof my_var.property !== 'undefined') ? my_var.property : 'fu';
```

I get:

Uncaught exception: ReferenceError: Undefined variable: my_var

well I know it's undefined, but why do I get that error?? xxx should take the fu value...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to check only `my_var` first, it can be `undefined`, too

```
var xxx = (typeof my_var !== 'undefined' && my_var.property !== 'undefined') ? my_var.property : 'fu';
```

Answer (score 5):

Your code checks if the type of `my_var.property` is undefined. But that *can't* be checked because the type of `my_var` *itself* is already undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Evaluation of `my_var.property` fails because my_var is null or undefined. Enhance your code like this:

```
var xxx = (my_var && typeof my_var.property !== 'undefined') ? my_var.property : 'fu';
```

Answer (score 2):

Add another check for `my_var`

```
var xxx =  (typeof my_var != 'undefined' && typeof my_var.property !== 'undefined')? my_var.property : 'fu';
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you should first check for my_var

```
if(!myvar) 
{
     var xxx = (typeof my_var.property !== 'undefined') ? my_var.property : 'fu';
     alert(xxx);
}
```